# Android studio error: resource not found Exception

Tags: android

i have a problem with my app:  i'm using crashlytics by Fabric, (my app is pubblishes in the play store) to have log of possible crash, and i have this error ".. MainActivity: android.content.res.Resource$NotFoundException:Resource ID#0x7f09001b"
(Crashlytics say to me that the device is a samsung galaxy s4 with Android 5.1 and root )

**CrashLytics screen**

[image]

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  <---- LINE 102 THAT GIVE 
                                                  THE ERROR , ACCORDING TO 
                                                       CRASHLYTICS

        ping = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ping);

        internet =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Internet);
        banda5Ghz =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.BandeSupp);
        SpeedNet =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.VR);
        ipv6 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.showIPv6);
        txVsegnale =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.intensità);
        aggiorna = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Aggiorna);
        share = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);
        clipboard = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.clipboard);
        rating = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ratebtn);
        IP =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.IP);
        showIPv4 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.showIPv4);
       // TextViewWifi =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewWifi);
        TextViewwifi_info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wifi_info);
        MacA = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.MacAdd);
        //switch gestione notifiche
        notifiche = (Switch)findViewById(R.id.switchNot);`
```

......

The same device crash 2 times in a short time, with same error.
My app is an app that show infos on your wifi connection, such as IP, network velocity, etc etc, also have system notification and widgets and a service that run in background .
I have also done different layout for different devices with different screen size and different screen dpi

**My Layouts**

[image]

No other  logs from other device with same problem .I want to know if is  a specific problem of this device ( may be related to root access given to this device ) or is a problem of my application.
Not sure if it is linked to this, but, i was tryeing to add split screen function to my app, and , adding  android:resizeableActivity="true"  to manifest, make app crash in the same code line, so, i solve by settings  to false and not include split screen feature in my app.
 I CONFIRMED THAT TRIEING TO USE SPLIT SCREEN GIVE ME THE SAME ERROR, SAME RESOURCE NOT FOUND EXCEPTION, how can i see which resource have this id ?
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f09001b
THE APP Crash only in this case , no other crash, do i have to define a minimum width and weight to use split Screen ?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.ShowMyIp.utente.ShowMyIp.MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Internet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="27dp"
    android:textColor="#646464"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Internet2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="195dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/internet4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/internet4"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/internet4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="195dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Internet"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Internet"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundcorner"
    android:textSize="13sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/MacAdd"
    android:layout_width="275dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtMac"
    android:layout_below="@+id/BandeSupp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="15sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/IP"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Internet"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Internet"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/internet4"
    android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
    android:text="IP Address"
    android:textColor="#E1E140"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showIPv4"
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/IP"
    android:layout_below="@+id/intensità"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wifi_info"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/showIPv4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/showIPv4"
    android:text="Non Connesso"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/velocita"
    android:layout_width="155dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/VR"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/txvIPV6"
    android:text="Velocità rete"
    android:textColor="#E1E140"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/VR"
    android:layout_width="135dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/wifi_info"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/velocita"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/Aggiorna"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/intensità"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Internet2"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_aggiorna" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/intensità"
    android:layout_width="190dp"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Internet"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/IP"
    android:layout_marginEnd="21dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMac"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/showIPv4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/internet4"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="MAC Address"
    android:textColor="#E1E140"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switchNot"
    android:layout_width="145dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/MacAdd"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Aggiorna"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:textColor="#E1E140"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    tools:text="Notifiche" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txvIPV6"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtMac"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Aggiorna"
    android:text="IPV6"
    android:textColor="#E1E140"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/showIPv6"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/MacAdd"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Aggiorna"
    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ratebtn"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/Internet2"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/rating_button"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sharebtn"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ratebtn"
    android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ratebtn"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/share_button" />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/clipboard"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sharebtn"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/VR"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/clipboard" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/BandeSupp"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txvIPV6"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/showIPv4"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:textSize="17sp" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ping"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/clipboard"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/switchNot"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ping" />


</RelativeLayout>`
```

here is my layout (large-port-mdpi)

App still crash entering in split screen mode, with "no found exception ..." ; i've made another  simple app , following Android developer guide to make multiview support, and this app work, no problem when entering in split screen, , i only added to the Manifest  same code i wrote  for this app "    android:resizeableActivity="true"". Anyone know about to resolve this error? why my app, dosen't find layout resource entering in split screen mode??

Comment: you can't take guarantee of rooted devices. Who knows what custom android they are using

Comment: ok,so, you suggest that is a problem related to this device ? I have done a lot of test on a lot of device and the app didn't crash , except when attempting to enter in  split screen mode  wich give me the same error, so , i set  android:resizeableActivity  to false

Comment: Yes rooted device causes problems with many apps. So that me be the case for you too

Comment: could the problem be that, i have specific layout  , for density and screen size, but, i haven't done all possible layout for all possible device with all possible density, and the s4  belongs to one i haven't made,and so   it dosen't found the layout? because i don't have a general layout

Comment: " i don't have a general layout" well, you should have else your app will crash if it does not find a fitting "special" layout. You can run a test by creating an emulator instance with mdpi and launching your app on it

Comment: according to my layouts screen, i try my app on an 10 inch emulator with wxga density (800 x1280   , mdpi) the app not crash even if i don't have a specific layout for it

Comment: Apart from specific layouts you should have a general layout which will be used if the phone specs doesn't matches with any of your specified folders

Comment: The device seems to have a screen size between normal and large and a xhdpi resolution, so I think you did provide the necessary layout resource. But besides being a resource, alayout file also references other resources: drawables, strings, dimen values etc. So if you want to be on the safe side you always have to provide a default version for everything.

Answer (score -1):

Check your MainActivity Layout Xml in Text Format, There Has to be Line with a Yellow Warning on it, Or a Red Line.

Check the Layout Xml, And Then,

Check If You Missed Something Like LinearLayout Being RelativeLayout and you Declared it with this mistake.

Then Check If You've Used Anything like below:

```js
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myRelativeLayout.getLayoutParams();

LinearLayout.LayoutParams Param1 = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) myLinearLayout.getLayoutParams();
```

If Yes, Reply me and I'll tell you what to do.

Comment: the only thing i notice is  that i have  for example     android:text="IPV6" and it sais "hardcode String, should use @String/Resource..." , i have a lot of these.Also, it sais on my imageButton : missing content attribute description on image; these are warning,i don't think they are the problem.I'm not using  in my application the code you have posted  upper.All layout are Relative

Comment: Are you Using ImageViews too?? If you're Using ImageView, Change it to AppCompatImageView, Also What is The Minimum API version of your App? It can be Simply a Texview that you haven't Set any Width or Height for it, It Can be a Relative Layout, Upload your Layout so we can see if there's anything wrong in it

Comment: Yes, Add a String Description to That ImageButton, It's gonna be Reference, But Yes, It's not the Cause of the Problem, But You Add a Description anyways

Comment: So, If your Layout is Relative, Then it Might be a View that you have Set the Height of it To Match_Parent and It's Stretching the Relative Layout to Fill the Screen, If it is, try Changing it, and Put the Relative Layout to Wrap_Parent

Comment: I'm not using imageView , but i'm using Image button 
  , with image that i converted from svg to xml, fro example 
    :   app:srcCompat="@drawable/share_button"   and share_button is an xml file that contain my svg image . Minimum API 19

Comment: ENrico, Thanks, Look at This In Your TextViews "internet4 and internet2",  android:layout_alignStart="@+id/Internet"
  And    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/internet4"     in Your TextViews... And you've Used   android:layout_width="match_parent"   Already, So REMOVE,  alignStart  &   alignEnd

Comment: I have found your Problem, You are Using AlignEnd, AlignStart, ALignBaseLine And All Kinds of Alignment  Along With a Specified HEight and Width, You Need to Either Remove All the Alignments, And only use Layout:Above & Layout:Below ,   Or, Keep the Alignments but you have to Remove Any Height and Width

Comment: thanks, i'll try  immediatly, then 
I'll let you know, for now thanks a lot

Comment: I just hope it doesn't get confusing, Alignments are a nightmare, try with patients

Comment: how can i find  which resource stand for "Resource ID #0x7f09001b" ? that is the resource give me the error? i assumed that it is the Main layout, due to line code that give the error is "setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);", but, only to be sure, i need to check, and i dont know hot to  do

Comment: my doubt, can SPLIT SCREEN FEATURES use in combination with rotation lock ? because my app is locked to portrait